# Add ArchLinux ISO to GRUB menu

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, grub

I wish to boot into ArchLinux ISO from the GRUB menu.
I have learnt that this can be achieved by adding a menuentry to the

`\etc\grub.d\40_custom`

And regenerating the grub using

`sudo update-grub`

If the ISO was an Ubuntu ISO, the following menuentry has to be added to the `\etc\grub.d\40_custom` file

```
menuentry “Ubuntu 14.04 ISO” {
set isofile=”/home/name/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso”
loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${isofile} quiet splash
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

But I need to boot from Arch Linux ISO. So what will should be the menuentry in this case?

If the answer varies with release, please explain the directory structure in ArchLinux ISO so that I can figure out values for each key like initd, linux, boot etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty well documented on the archlinux wiki, with entries for each distro. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive#Arch_Linux

You could use:

```
menuentry '[loopback]archlinux-2014.12.01-dual.iso' {
  set isofile='/boot/iso/archlinux-2014.12.01-dual.iso'
  set imgdevpath='/dev/disk/by-uuid/youruuid'
  loopback loop $isofile
  linux (loop)/arch/boot/x86_64/vmlinuz archisodevice=/dev/loop0 img_dev=$imgdevpath img_loop=$isofile earlymodules=loop
  initrd (loop)/arch/boot/x86_64/archiso.img
}
```

You have to customize the path of the iso file.

Comment: Thank you. That should work :) Will comeback if I have any problem